# iOS5 Upgrade fails with Error 3014

Tags: iphone, ios

While upgrading to iOS5, my iPhone 4 got crushed.

Here is the log from the upgrade process:

```
Oct 12 23:23:24 qwertzuiop usbmuxd[38]: AMDeviceConnect (thread 0x100781000): This is not the droid you're looking for (is actually com.apple.mobile.restored). Move along, move along.
Oct 12 23:23:24 qwertzuiop usbmuxd[38]: _AMDevicePreflightWorker (thread 0x100781000): Pair worker could not connect to lockdownd on device 3: 0xe8000028.
Oct 12 23:23:24 qwertzuiop iTunesHelper[790]: _AMDDeviceAttachedCallbackv3 (thread 0x7fff76d4c960): Device 'AMDevice 0x100436990 {UDID = ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff, device ID = 3, location ID = 0x24100000, product ID = 0x1297}' attached.
Oct 12 23:23:24 qwertzuiop iTunes[785]: _AMDDeviceAttachedCallbackv3 (thread 0x10abde000): Device 'AMDevice 0x7fe3cadbb000 {UDID = ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff, device ID = 3, location ID = 0x24100000, product ID = 0x1297}' attached.
Oct 12 23:23:24 qwertzuiop iTunesHelper[790]: AMDeviceConnect (thread 0x7fff76d4c960): This is not the droid you're looking for (is actually com.apple.mobile.restored). Move along, move along.
Oct 12 23:23:24 qwertzuiop iTunes[785]: AMDeviceConnect (thread 0x10abde000): This is not the droid you're looking for (is actually com.apple.mobile.restored). Move along, move along.
Oct 12 23:23:24 qwertzuiop iTunesHelper[790]: AMDeviceConnect (thread 0x7fff76d4c960): This is not the droid you're looking for (is actually com.apple.mobile.restored). Move along, move along.
Oct 12 23:23:24 qwertzuiop iTunes[785]: AMDeviceConnect (thread 0x10abde000): This is not the droid you're looking for (is actually com.apple.mobile.restored). Move along, move along.
Oct 12 23:24:01 qwertzuiop com.apple.usbmuxd[38]: MuxTCPInputSCE received RST for 0x3-ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff@0x24100000:12345->0x100318240-iTunes/com.apple.iTunes:18432: handleConnectResult: failure - 61
Oct 12 23:24:01 qwertzuiop com.apple.usbmuxd[38]: MuxTCPInputSCE received RST for 0x3-ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff@0x24100000:12345->0x101828bb0-iTunes/com.apple.iTunes:18688: handleConnectResult: failure - 61
Oct 12 23:27:25 qwertzuiop iTunesHelper[790]: _AMDDeviceDetached (thread 0x7fff76d4c960): Device 'AMDevice 0x100436990 {UDID = ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff, device ID = 3, location ID = 0x24100000, product ID = 0x1297}' detached.
Oct 12 23:27:25 qwertzuiop iTunes[785]: _AMDDeviceDetached (thread 0x10abde000): Device 'AMDevice 0x7fe3cadbb000 {UDID = ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff, device ID = 3, location ID = 0x24100000, product ID = 0x1297}' detached.
```

Upgrading stuck with a 3014 error. Any help highly appreciated.

**Update**: Apple says error 3014 tends to appear when there is not enough free disk space on your Mac. Actually I have only 6GB left on my hard drive, I will try to free more space and try upgrading again.

Comment: 6GB free??? Wish I had that much :) Thanks for sharing the log - love the first line...

Comment: I free'd up more than 32GB and after that it worked... Thank science I have a huge external drive.

Answer (score 5):

Today, it means the Apple server is overwhelmed.  Try again tomorrow.

Comment: Yes, I got that error 4-5 times today, but finally got through.

Answer (score 3):

The 3014 upgrade error was resolved by freeing up disk space on my mac.

Answer (score 0):

iTunes always logs an error when this fails - in your case, the text has the following tips:

> Error codes in the 3000 range generally mean that iTunes cannot contact the gs.apple.com server on ports 80 or 443. This may be because out-of-date or incorrectly configured security or firewall software is interfering, an old version of iTunes is installed, an entry in your hosts file redirecting requests to gs.apple.com (see error 1004 above), or because of your Internet proxy settings.

- [iTunes: Specific update-and-restore error messages and advanced troubleshooting](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS3694)

Generic steps are worth checking if you haven't recently updated iTunes or the device - especially if the specific error message steps don't help.

- [iOS: Resolving update and restore alert messages](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS1275)